# Swift string format specifier equivalent to %@

Tags: xcode, string, swift, format

I am writing a simple app with a form in Swift, I had the app written in Objective-C to populate an e-Mail with data from text fields in a view, I used the following code to do this:

```c
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@ \nDate: %@", NameField.text, DateField.text];
```

I am trying to achieve the same thing in Swift, I have the following so far:

```swift
let messageBody = NSString(format: "Name: %@ \nDate: %@", NameField, DateField)
```

I am looking for swifts equivalent to `"%@"` to make the app look to the format of the string to find the data to place after `"Name:"`.

Comment: I don't see where is your issue, it works the same in Swift. Your Swift example works. Of course you could always use Swift's String interpolation instead. You don't *need* to change anything. But you can, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just port Obj-c to Swift. Swift has it's own way of doing things.

```
let message = "Name: \(nameField) \nDate:\(dateField)"
```

Comment: This example is using Swift's string interpolation. However, its sometimes desirable to use string format specifiers like the OP is asking about (i.e., for string localization). For the string format specifier of type `string` you can use `%@`. Here's two examples using `String`, not `NSString`: `String.localizedStringWithFormat("Name: %@", name)` and 
`String(format: "Name: %@", name)`

Answer (score 14):

In Swift you use `\(some_printable_object_or_string)`

like

```
let string = "Name: \(NameField) \nDate: \(DateField)"
```

Or you can use ObjectiveC-style formatting

```
let string = String(format: "Name: %@ \nDate: %@", NameField, DateField)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)

```
    let firstName = "Hai"
    let date = NSDate()
    let messageBody = NSString(format: "Name: \(firstName) \n Date: \(date)")
    NSLog(messageBody as String)
```